# I want to check if three sides of a triangle is a right angle using the Pythagoras theory by calling a function

Tags: c++

I want to call a function to calculate Pythagoras and to see whether it is true that a triangle is a right angled triangle using three inputs. I am very new to C++ and will appreciate help with this:

This is my code, it runs but does not work correctly:

```
    #include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 

using namespace std;

double pythagorusTheorem(double a, double b, double c);

int main(){

double a;
double b;
double c;

cout << "Write the three sides of the triangle, enter biggest first and shorter sides after: " << endl;

cin >> a >> b >> c; 



if (double val=pythagorusTheorem(a,b,c) == true){

cout << "This is a right-angle triangle " << endl;

}

if (double val=pythagorusTheorem(a,b,c) == false) {

cout << "This is not a right angled triangle " << endl; 

}

return 0;
}


double pythagorusTheorem(double a, double b, double c){

a = pow(b,2) + pow(c,2);



}
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work as supposed?

Comment: What do you mean by this line `if (double val=pythagorusTheorem(a,b,c) == true)` ?

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways for something to not work correctly. Please be more specific.

Comment: When I enter three input a, b and c it does not tell me whether is rightangled or not using the cout output

Comment: I meant by the line "if (double val=pythagorusTheorem(a,b,c) == true) " if C^2 = a^2 + a^2 then it is a right angled triangle

Comment: To prove Pythagorus Theorem, it can' be a = pow(b,2) + pow(c,2); you have to calculate the square root, as the theorem states a^2 = b^2 + c^2 where a is the hypothenuse. Also instead of two if, maybe you could use else?

Answer (score 1):

You don't return a value from `pythagorusTheorem`. This is **undefined behaviour**. In addition:

```
if (double val=pythagorusTheorem(a,b,c) == true)
```

...reaaaally doesn't do what you expect. Remember that `==` is for comparing if two values are equal, but `=` is for assigning a value to a variable.

You'd be much better suited by changing the function to one which returns true or false depending on if your values fulfill the required condition:

```
bool pythagorasTheorem(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return a*a == b*b + c*c;
}
```

Then change your comparisons to:

```
if (pythagorasTheorem(a,b,c))
{
    cout << "This is a right-angle triangle " << endl;
}
```

I have to refer you to this [lovely list of C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - you should read up on functions, in particular. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) will likely also be helpful.

Comment: Given this, you just need to say `if (pythagorusTheorem(a, b, c))`; you *almost never* need to compare to `true` or `false` explicitly.

Comment: @DanielH Caught me mid-edit, sorry...

Comment: Multiplication is more efficient than calling the `pow` function, so `a * a` would be more efficient than `pow(a, 2)`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah, I was trying to stay in the vein of the original code. I'll edit though, as I suppose I've ripped enough of OP's original code up anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your function like this:

```
bool pythagorasTheorem(double a, double b, double c)
{
    a *= a;
    b *= b;
    c *= c;
    return a == b + c || b == c + a || c == a + b;
}
```

using @hnefatl solution, you don't have to enter longest side first